# refund PayPal in Express check out

Tags: php, api, paypal, express-checkout

I'm using PayPal Express checkout api for selling my item in my website. In my website I'm guaranteeing that if user had any issue with the item I will refund the money. So I was wondering is there any script for refund ? And after how long can I refund the money ? Is there any limited time for refund ? And also Is there any charge from Paypal for refunding ? Thanks

Comment: All of your questions must be answered by paypal.

Answer (score 2):

You can find sample code about refund on express checkout [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples)

PayPal does not charge the refund if it is issued up to 60 days.

AFAIK if you wish to refund in more than 60 days, you have to send money as a new transaction. Thus PayPal will apply its commision fee.